# quit the loop when return true with curl exec

Tags: php

### -------1.txt-----------

```
wrongpass1   <----- return 120
wrongpass2   <----- return 120
truepass     <----- return 1000
wrongpass3   <----- return 120
```

---

------login.php---------

```html
 $file = fopen("1.txt","r");

while(! feof($file))
{
 $line = fgets($file);
 $leng = strlen($line);
 //echo $leng;
 //echo $line;
 
  $ch = curl_init();                    // initiate curl
   $url = "http://localhost/login.php"; // where you want to post data
   $pass = "pass=".$line;
   $data_string = $pass;                                                                                   

   $ch = curl_init('http://localhost/login.php');                                                                      
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
   //$result = curl_exec($ch);
   while ($result = curl_exec($ch))
   { 
    $data_len = strlen ($result);
    if($data_len >120)
    {
     echo $data_len . "<br />";
     echo $line;
     break;
    }
    break;
   }

}
 fclose($file);
```

it always return 120,120,120,120.
how to fix it to display 120,120,1000,120 ?

if you delete wrongpass3, it will return 120,120,1000.
But if truepass is among of them, it only return 120,120,120,120.

Comment: why are you doing a `while` on your curl results? you only need to do **ONE** curl request to test your pass. As such, `break` is breaking out of the `while($result`, not the `while(!feof`

Comment: how can it return 120 when you only have an echo in the if branch which excludes that ?

Comment: Hi Marc B, how can i edit that code? i really crazy with it :(, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to determine the number of bytes sent back. For example:

```php
$file = fopen("1.txt","r");

while(! feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    $leng = strlen($line);
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = "http://localhost/login.php";
    $pass = "pass=".$line;
    $data_string = $pass;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if($infp['size_download'] > 120){
        echo "{$infp['size_download']}<br />";
        echo $line;
        break;
    }
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: you could put your $line = fgets($file) inside the while loop and test the same. This will reduce your code by one line and speed up your code by removing one less operation. `while(!($line = fgets($file))`